# How to efficiently detect bar code target in an image

Tags: image

I have two questions:

Firstly, how to detect the area of bar code target in an image (like the sample images), which may have a few noises.

Secondly, how to efficiently do the detection, for instance, in 1/30 seconds.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have two questions: What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you have any other images, or are they all very similar to the one shown?

Comment: I have added another sample image that the target is much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squash (resize) the image till it is only 1 pixel tall, then normalise it to the full range of 0-255 and threshold. I am using ImageMagick at the command-line here - it is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows also with Python, PHP, Ruby, C/C++ bindings.

```
convert barcode.png -resize x1! -scale x10! -normalize -threshold 50% result.png
```

[image]

I have then scaled it to 10 pixels tall so you can actually see it on here - but you would keep the original width and have a height of one pixel. Then just find the first white pixel in your single row of pixels.

Your recently added, smaller barcode gives this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efficient method. I think you mean that we sum the value of pixel along the column, then normalize and threshold, so we can identify the y-coordinate of the target. We can do it along the row, and find the  x-coordinate of the target. Finally, we can do refined work in the area defined by the (x, y). I will try it in matlab and get back to you soon.

Comment: Excellent! Good luck!